# If path not taken in return statement in react unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am getting the message in  that the "if path not taken" for i applied condition for save & update action on basis of id undefined case.
Please guide me how to i write test case in which id is undefined or not undefined & also return statement covered.

i apply both update & add data action on one click button so i apply condition if id is null or undefined than perform saveCampaignGroup() save data action perform. if id is not null or not undefined  than in else condition updateCampaignGroup(id); action perform.

```
{(() => {
      if (id === undefined || id === '') {
        return (
          <Wizard.Step
            title="Review and save"
            isValid={true}
            actions={{
              primary: {
                label: 'Complete and save',
                onClick: () => {
                  saveCampaignGroup();
                },
              },
            }}>
            <PreviewDetails
              details={inputState}
              campaigns={selectedCampaigns}
              NoCampaignExist={NoCampaignExist}
            />
          </Wizard.Step>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <Wizard.Step
            title="Review and save"
            isValid={true}
            actions={{
              primary: {
                label: 'Complete and save',
                onClick: () => {
                  updateCampaignGroup(id);
                },
              },
            }}>
            <PreviewDetails
              details={inputState}
              campaigns={selectedCampaigns}
              NoCampaignExist={NoCampaignExist}
            />
          </Wizard.Step>
        );
      }
    })()}
```

[in this image you can see by default else is covered but id via test case we set id=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23rRZ.png)

Comment: Please help me any bodu for unit testing in react

Comment: You should give us more context. What is this `id` you want to test?

Comment: i apply both update & add data action on one click button so i apply condition if id is null or undefined than perform saveCampaignGroup() save data action perform. if id is not null or not undefined  than in else condition updateCampaignGroup(id); action perform.

Comment: You didn't understand me: how do you declare this id in your component? Is it a prop, a state, a local variable, a global variable? Sho the code if possible...

Comment: yes id is prop in this child componant

Comment: hI  k-wasilewski Please help us how i write test case for above code

Comment: Then you can simpy pass `id={undefined}` (which is equal to not passing it at all) as a component's prop; then test it.

Comment: yes but how to i perform saveCampaignGroup()  save data  & updateCampaignGroup(id); update data on single button on-click action perform. for both operation i apply if & else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to apply a :

```
component.find('#your_button_id').at(0).simulate('click');
```

for both testing scenarios: one for a component with with a valid `id` prop and one for the one without it.

Comment: Thanks and i try to it

Comment: Hi k-wasilewski can yu also see my this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844760/test-coverage-very-low-due-to-these-code-campaigngrouplisting-findindexitem